# Mysql one to many relationship. Order by number of rows in second table

Tags: php, mysql, table-relationships

I have created a voting system in php and mysql. When a user votes on an id, a record is inserted in "votes" referencing the FK media_id. When I then display the entries I use this query to get the number of votes for each entry:

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM insta_votes WHERE media_id ='".$mediaid."'";
if ($res = $db->query($sql)) {
    return $res->fetchColumn();
}
return 0;
```

This works fine, but I want to be able to sort the results by the number of votes they have. Preferably using just one query. How can I achieve this?

The tables are structured like this:

```
votes table
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field     | Type         | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| id        | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
| media_id  | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| ip        | varchar(20)  | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| c_time    | timestamp    | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                |
| sessionid | varchar(30)  | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+

entries table
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
| Field         | Type         | Null | Key | Default           | Extra |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
| page_id       | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL              |       |
| media_id      | varchar(255) | NO   | PRI | NULL              |       |
| url           | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL              |       |
| c_time        | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL              |       |
| likes         | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL              |       |
| deleted       | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | 0                 |       |
| inserted_time | timestamp    | YES  |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |       |
| numReports    | int(11)      | NO   |     | 0                 |       |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
```

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried `ORDER BY`?

Comment: The problem is that I want to get the records in the entries table ordered by the number of records with that media_id in the votes table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand the tables correctly (and I may not), each `entries` row may reference multiple `votes` rows. In that case, the query you need will go something like this:

```
SELECT
  entries.page_id,
  COUNT(*) AS VoteCount
FROM entries
INNER JOIN votes ON entries.media_id = votes.media_id
GROUP BY entries.page_id
ORDER BY VoteCount
```

If you add additional `entries` columns to the `SELECT` list, be sure to add them to the `GROUP BY` list as well.

---

**Addendum**: @JuanPabloCalifano pointed out, correctly, that this query won't include entries with zero votes. Here's how to include them:

```
SELECT
  entries.page_id,
  COALESCE(COUNT(votes.id), 0) AS VoteCount
FROM entries
LEFT JOIN votes ON entries.media_id = votes.media_id
GROUP BY entries.page_id
ORDER BY VoteCount
```

Comment: Excellent! Worked perfect with a little modification:
    SELECT * , COUNT( * ) AS VoteCount
FROM insta_entries
INNER JOIN insta_votes ON insta_entries.media_id = insta_votes.media_id
GROUP BY insta_entries.media_id
ORDER BY VoteCount

Comment: Bear in mind that if you do an inner join, entries without votes won't be listed. I think you need a left join here.

Comment: Good catch @JuanPabloCalifano! I really do know better than that :) Cobradelaplaya - if you need to include entries with zero votes please see the addendum to my answer.

Comment: @Ed Gibbs. Thanks. I don't mean to nitpick but the group by should be done separately. Otherwise COUNT(*) will return always 1 (since it'll be counting the number of rows after they've been grouped).

Comment: That's not nitpicking because we're talking about an actual error here, and *really* I know better :) I've just fixed the problem by changing from `COUNT(*)` to `COUNT(votes.id)`. Time for more coffee...

Comment: Great! By the way, I thought you needed to do a subquery but now I see in your solution that you just need to count the other column to get the right value.

Comment: I love this solution! This is more elegant than a subquery.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as CNT, `media_id` FROM `insta_votes` GROUP BY `media_id` order by 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*), media_id FROM insta_votes 
GROUP BY media_id 
ORDER BY COUNT(*);"
```